# When I solicit a "Miriam" font from Windows, I get an "Arial" font. How is this possible, as the font file "mriam.ttf" exists in my system?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, fonts

In the code that follows, the `Miriam` font is created in `WM_CREATE` and its family name is obtained in a static `OUTLINETEXTMETRIC struct`, pointed by `s_potm`. Then I exhibit the member `otmpFamilyName` of this structure in `WM_PAINT`, and I get the string `Arial` printed on the window client area, instead of `Miriam`. But there is no reason for this font substitution, as the font file `mriam.ttf` exists in Windows 7. Any explanation ?

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, UINT, LONG);

int APIENTRY WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR pszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX  wndclassx;

    wndclassx.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndclassx.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclassx.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wndclassx.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wndclassx.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wndclassx.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wndclassx.hIcon         = 0;
    wndclassx.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclassx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wndclassx.lpszMenuName  = 0;
    wndclassx.lpszClassName = L"WndProc";
    wndclassx.hIconSm       = 0;

    if( !RegisterClassEx(&wndclassx) ) return 0;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"WndProc", 0, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                             0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;

    while( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) )
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    //  Retorna msg.wParam

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, UINT wParam, LONG lParam)
{
    static OUTLINETEXTMETRIC* s_potm;

    switch ( message )
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HDC hDC;
            if( !(hDC = CreateIC(L"Display", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr)) ) return -1;

            LOGFONT lf;
            memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));
            lf.lfHeight = 20;
            lf.lfOutPrecision = OUT_TT_ONLY_PRECIS;
            wcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE, L"Miriam");

            HFONT hFont;
            if( !(hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf)) )
            {
                DeleteDC(hDC);
                return -1;
            }

             hFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hDC, hFont);

             int ix = GetOutlineTextMetrics(hDC, 0, nullptr);

             s_potm = (OUTLINETEXTMETRIC*)new char[ix];

             GetOutlineTextMetrics(hDC, ix, s_potm); 

             DeleteObject(SelectObject(hDC, hFont));
             DeleteDC(hDC);
        }
        break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            wchar_t* p = (wchar_t*)((BYTE*)s_potm + (int)s_potm->otmpFamilyName);
            TextOut(ps.hdc, 10, 20, p, wcslen(p)); 
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        default:

        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit :** the same thing happens with the font `MT Extra`

Comment: Depends what foundry you got this from, but the Linotype version of Miriam is an OpenType font, not a TrueType font.  Exactly how to use OpenType is a pretty well kept secret, I only know of WPF's support for it.

Comment: What is the value of lf.lfFaceName after the wcscpy_s call? LF_FACESIZE is 32, maybe you need to specify the exact length.

Comment: @HansPassant `Arial, Calibri, Cambria and Times New Roman` are all OpenType fonts. If you replace the `Miriam`font on the code by any one of those fonts, you'll get the correct result in the `otmpFamilyName` member.

Comment: @kol `lf.lfFaceName` contains the zero terminated string "Miriam".

Comment: I certainly recognize those font names, they are TrueType fonts on my machine, not OT fonts.  On any Windows machine afaik.

Comment: I can garantee you, they're all OpenType fonts. They have, for instance, the tables GSUB and GPOS, which don't exist in a pure TT font.

Comment: What's the reason for the down vote ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you ask Windows for a font, it tries its best to match *all* of the criteria you listed in the LOGFONT structure. Some fields take precedence over others. You've left most of the values at zero.

I think in this case it's the `lfCharSet` field that's throwing you off. Zero equates to `ANSI_CHARSET`, but Miriam doesn't look like an ANSI font.

The MSDN documentation says about `lfCharSet`:

> This parameter is important in the font mapping process. To ensure consistent results, specify a specific character set. If you specify a typeface name in the lfFaceName member, make sure that the lfCharSet value matches the character set of the typeface specified in lfFaceName.

Comment: Congratulations ! Making lf.lfCharSet = HEBREW_CHARSET evething works fine. But I don't understand how the lfCharSet field can have a higher priority than the FaceName, when Windows decides which font to choose. Do you have any explanation ?

Comment: @user1162978, I guess Windows considers it more important to display the proper characters than the proper font. Arial is supplied in a Unicode variant that can display almost anything, the number of characters it contains is just massive.

Comment: But if I use "Arabic Typesetting" in place of "Miriam" I'll get the correct font family name, event though "Arabic Typesetting" doesn't have an ANSI_CHARSET either.

Comment: Arial Unicode MS is a last-resort font (read: Never use it at all – and in fact there is no need to on today's systems) and not distributed with Windows. It's part of Office.